# Batch File Copy and Rename

Tags: windows, batch-file

Currently looking to copy and rename a file from a C:Drive source to a G:Drive destination by using a batch file. Currently have the following code:

```
robocopy C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Test G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup  /e /purge
ren G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup accessbackup.jpg backup.jpg
```

The file will successfully copy, but there is no rename. Do I need to specify a file I am looking to rename? My batch file will copy an entire folder to another destination, unsure if that is the problem here...

Comment: You have to use `ren "G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup accessbackup.jpg" backup.jpg` as there is a space in name of file to rename. Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and read in the output help at least the last paragraph on last output page to get informed when a file/folder name or any other argument string __must__ be enclosed in double quotes. Or use `ren G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\accessbackup.jpg backup.jpg` if the file `accessbackup.jpg` is in the folder of which path is specified too.

Comment: Hi Mofi. The rename is still not working: 'xcopy C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Test\accessbackup.jpg G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup  /e /purge
ren "G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\accessbackup.jpg" backup.jpg'

Comment: Does `G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\backup.jpg` exist already? Yes, then it is not possible to rename a different file to `backup.jpg`. What is the error message output? You can see the error message on opening a command prompt window and run the commands respectively the batch file from within the command prompt window. I prefer the command `move` to rename a file which would be for this example: `move /Y "G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\accessbackup.jpg" "G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\backup.jpg"`. The option `/Y` results in overwriting an existing file with that name.

Comment: There is no `/PURGE` option for [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), you seem to confuse it with [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)...

Comment: @abronk, your question title specifically uses the term `TimeStamp` however your question or the supplied commands neither make mention of nor indicate that term as being relevant. Also there seems to be confusion about what you're trying to do; your question indicates you are only wanting to copy a file to another location with a different name but your commands appear to be related to copying a directory. Can you please clarify each by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47754809/edit) as necessary.

Comment: Progress! I was able to accomplish the task. Here is the batch file: "DEL G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\test.jpg
SLEEP 5
xcopy C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Test\accessbackup.jpg G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup
ren "G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\accessbackup.jpg" test.jpg"

Comment: @abronk, even if a pause was necessary, _(doubtful)_, there's no native `SLEEP` command. Also did you consider using the `Copy` command? `Copy /Y "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Test\accessbackup.jpg" "G:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\Backup\test.jpg"`

Comment: @Compo you are correct. I now have this: "copy /Y C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Test\accessbackup.jpg G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup\test1.jpg" and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you `ren` syntax is not correct.
Maybe try the following after copying the directory

```
pushd G:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Backup
ren accessbackup.jpg backup.jpg
popd
```

This way you will temporarily change your working directory to the sink-path and then change it back

Comment: thank you for the response, I was able to get a fully working batch file with some changes. Here is what I have: "DEL /Q "C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Back up\*.*"
copy /Y C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Test\accessbackup.jpg "C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Back up\GtCopy.jpg"
ren "C:\Users\abronk04\Desktop\Back up\GtCopy.jpg" "GtCopy%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-4,4%.jpg"". The file will delete old copies, make a new copy, and then rename the new copy with a time stamp. Note - this is all happening as a test, so it is all on the C drive.